# WIX Error 1327. Invalid Drive

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have windows service installation process, which worked before untill today.

When I run `msiexec /i "C:\installation.msi" /log "C:\logs.log"  TARGETDIR=C:\destinationPath`

I got error: E`rror 1327. Invalid Drive: D:\`
In logs I can see TARGETDIR repeated 3 times:

```
Property(N): TARGETDIR = D:\
Property(S): TARGETDIR = C:\
Property(C): TARGETDIR = C:\
```

In Wix I have

```
<Property Id="TARGETDIR"/>
```

And installation

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory...
```

What can be wrong that firt value of property TARGETDIR is D ? I don't have this drive, can it be cache, or some windows key ? Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help to see more of the verbose log, but if the only log entries related to cached products are as you posted then you are not doing a fresh install. A fresh setup will say something about running from the actual MSI file, and will not refer to cached context. That implies that your ProductCode (or sometimes PackageCode) is still installed on the system, and you are NOT installing your MSI product - you are causing a maintenance mode operation on that already installed product, and that's what is looking for a D:\ drive.

The fact that you removed all those registry entries and it worked confirms this, but it would have been preferable to locate that installed product and uninstall it. There are all kinds of registry entries related to PackageCode, UpgradeCode, Component IDs that may still cause issues. If you were to ask Windows which products are using a particular Component ID you may find it believes there are two. If you uninstall your product does it remove all the files and run any custom actions successfully? If the ref counting of component Ids is wrong that's the kind of thing that can happen.

Comment: so how can I do fresh install ? any more parameter to msiexec /i "C:\installation.msi" /log "C:\logs.log"  TARGETDIR=C:\destinationPath ?

Answer (score 0):

when I dumped all logs using `/lvoicewarmupx`
I saw

```
MSI (s) (D0:0C) [18:55:43:619]: Using cached product context: machine assigned for product: EDA754DD57D2E6245809CEAB950DA2D7
MSI (s) (D0:0C) [18:55:43:619]: Note: 1: 1327 2: D:\
```

Then I removed from registry all entries for key `EDA754DD57D2E6245809CEAB950DA2D7`

And Problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

We have experienced a similar problem "Inavlid Drive A:"  on installs where users are either:

- Trying to run the MSI from a zip
- Trying to run the MSI from a network location